# Filter Design Preparatory Book Recommendation

Tags: design, filter, passive-networks

It is generally agreed that Zverev's "Handbook of Filter Design" is *THE* reference work for LC filter design.  However, I crack it open, and the first thing he does is head off into lattice filter theory, and I don't have that background.

I have a rudimentary grasp of elementary RLC circuit analysis (steady-state, not impulse) (first EE circuit analysis class).  Can anyone suggest book(s) suitable for getting me from there to ready to tackle Zverev?

My interest is casual design of HF and VHF receiver preselector filters, and HF and VHF transmitter output harmonic suppression filters, for amateur radio applications.  I am *NOT* afraid of math; I am *NOT* afraid of numbercrunching; I am *NOT* afraid of MATLAB (GNU Octave, usually).

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: [Electronic Filter Design](https://www.amazon.com.br/Electronic-Filter-Design-Handbook-Fourth/dp/0071471715), by W&T is the best source to go through filter design techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to design filters without going through all the maths, [Elsie](http://www.tonnesoftware.com/elsie.html) by James Tonne is excellent. The free version should do what you want, and even if you need to buy the full version, it's a lot cheaper than Zverev's book. I've checked filters designed with it with SPICE, and the response is virtually identical.

Comment: That's actually a very nice link.  I just picked up a copy of the current ARRL Handbook last weekend, and hadn't yet gotten around to loading the CD.  I'll take a look at it.  My goal on this question is to understand the math, understand the design theory, as I've found I get better results when I actually know what's going on.

Comment: Download it, the version of the CD-ROM will be quite old.

Comment: Looks like nobody else has any suggestions.

Comment: First impression of Elsie: In order to escape from a loop around a "try again" dialogue, when I entered a bad set of values, I had to force a divide-by-zero fatal error.  Not a good start...

Comment: OK, second try, didn't hit the problem above, and this package looks really good.  So I guess one really bad design error is excusable.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Analog Electronic Filters](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9789400721890), by Dimopoulos Hercules is second probably only to Zverev's. It contains almost everything, and it requires reasonably little knowledge on electrical networks. It also contains a lengthy appendix on Mathematics needed for circuit and filter design and finally another appendix that covers some basic topics on network theory and Op-Amps. It provides many types of intricate circuits used when designing filters and has many recommendations about them. Overall it's a very well written book, but beware that filter analysis has a lot of math. In the website you can also view samples from the book. Hope this helps.